# Is a substring of a random number a random number?

Tags: probability, distribution

Assume I have a large list of random integers with an even distribution between `000000` and `999999` inclusive.

Now assume I take the first 3 digits of each of those numbers.

Are those numbers guaranteed to have an even distribution between `000` and `999` inclusive?

What if I take the last three digits?

What if the the random integers are in hex, or any other base (but still one character per digit)?

Practical application: could a cryptographic hash—which by definition should have an even distribution between its minimum and maximum values—be used to generate a random but consistent number of arbitrary bounds, given an input (that is, the data being hashed)?

Comment: `Practical application: could a cryptographic hash—which by definition should have an even distribution between its minimum and maximum values—be used to generate a random but consistent number ` Yes, famous one being [Fortuna RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortuna_(PRNG))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking either the first three or the last three digits will give you a random and uniformly distributed three-digit number. Indeed, you can pick both and get two random and independent numbers, each with a uniform distribution, as long as the digits you pick for each number don't overlap.

(So you could pick digits 1, 3, and 4 as the first number and 6, 2, and 5 as the last number and they would still be random and independent in the `000`-`999` range.)

This is because we can consider your `000000`-`999999` -generator as consisting of 6 independent 1-digit generators with a uniform probability-distribution.

This still works for `000000`-`FFFFFF` in hex, but obviously not `000000`-`0F423F` (999999).

As long as you stick to a positional system like hex, binary, decimal etc. and allow the full possible span of characters, this works.

EDIT:
I am not sure that I understand your generating bounds with the hash.

Comment: By _generating bounds with the hash_, I just mean that my bounds would be the range of possible values for the hash. For example: a 256-bit hash would have `2^256` possible values, or a range of `[0,2^256 – 1]`. That is, if I'm understanding hashes and your EDIT correctly.

Comment: But this is a helpful answer. Thank you. Could you please just define "positional system" for me? Does that mean each digit can be represented by an isolatable portion of the number's string (eg: one character == one digit)?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, all kinds of number systems we use today are positional. So moving a digit one place to the left multiplies its value with some number (normally 10, or 2 in binary etc.) Roman numerals on the other hand are extremely 'un-positional' if that's a thing, in that V and VIII only differs by the addition of the extra 3 I and not the position of V.